# What should one do with media assets related to a Git repository?

Tags: git, github, assets

Some of the simple examples of GitHub practice will include addition or deletion of code in HTML/CSS files.

However, what should one do with media assets (which may be central to a web app)? Is it feasible or worthwhile to use Git and/or GitHub to store media assets such as images, or even video? What's considered best practice?

After reading [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3618447/using-git-for-images), it seems to me that Git can possibly store some kind of acknowledgement that they exist as part of a project. In addition, this [link](http://solutionoptimist.com/2013/12/28/awesome-github-tricks/) gives some good tips for dealing with assets.

What should I do with those assets?

Comment: I would stick to storing assets which are used by your code, like a png which contains all the sub-assets for your website, like icons, etc. I've stored logos and other assets before, but I wouldn't see myself storing videos in a github repo. You have to remember that all of the videos and their distinct version will be fully saved. Cloning will start to be a nightmare. Keep it simple and for other bigger files (videos, etc) use typical storage, maybe tag it in folder which go along github folders: `website/v1/videos/video1.mkv`. just my oppinion.

Comment: Thanks for your advice which sound like good suggestions. I agree that storing video on Git Hub repo doesnt seem like the wisest thing to do. Most tutorials dont discuss the use of media assets or images hence my question, but it seems that according to the git hub manual, 1gb is the recommended size limit to a repository, which is still rather alot! Best then I suppose to leave it to a judgement call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This information](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80962/should-images-be-stored-in-a-git-repository) on Stack Exchange was helpful

It seems that some people are proponents of using [submodules](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule) within git, or even creating a separate repository for images/assets. Some say using a third party like Dropbox can help, or [Unison](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/).  Others find it *necessary* to include assets in version control.

As far as I can see, uploading assets to a Git Hub repo wont degrade images so there is no reason not to, within the [recommended 1gb limit.](https://help.github.com/articles/what-is-my-disk-quota/). To conclude, as with most things, it all depends on your requirements and circumstances at the time.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like nowadays assets or media data can be handled using
DVC (Data version control system): https://dvc.org/ to keep repositories nice and thin (or at least under required size limitation).

Comment: Especially for data science and machine learning project, but yes: DVC is great for tracking large files in parallel to git repos in general.

Answer (score 1):

It is definitely possible to use Git Hub as a cloud for your media content. I don't think it's against their terms of service since you are utilizing their tools. The only thing that concerns me is your privacy. Your content will be accessible by thousands of users across the internet.

Comment: Yes agreed, I was very surprised to learn that the size limit of a GitHub repo is 1GB. So in effect the answer is you can store what you want, if you want, within reason.